# Command fails via 'bash -c' but works directly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

The command fails via `bash -c`:

```
bash -c 'sudo lspci -vvv | awk \'/System peripheral/ {portn=$1} /Status:/ {split($3,a,"M");printf "%s\n",a[1]}\''
```

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

The same command works well if is run directly in the console `sudo lspci -vvv | awk '/System peripheral/ {portn=$1} /Status:/ {split($3,a,"M");printf "%s\n",a[1]}'`

How to cover '(' in the command string for bash -c ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot escape single quotes inside single quotes that way. It does not work.

Your command is being seen as

```
sudo lspci -vvv | awk /System peripheral/ {portn=$1} /Status:/ {split($3,a,"M");printf "%s\n",a[1]}
```

which fails.

To place a single quote inside a single quoted string you need to use `'\''`.

So your command becomes:

```
bash -c 'sudo lspci -vvv | awk '\''/System peripheral/ {portn=$1} /Status:/ {split($3,a,"M");printf "%s\n",a[1]}'\'
```